# What does this example mean? Slow cooling of 40% Sn alloy from 800°C to 600°C: L → L and γ → L, γ, and ε → L and ε

Tags: physical-chemistry

It's in a phase diagram topic. It's about $\ce{Cu}$-$\ce{Sn}$ phase diagram.

[image]
And it has a question of:

> Write the schematic diagram describing the following scenarios and identifies the regions and the phases when Slow cooling of $13.1\%$ $\ce{Sn}$ alloy from $\pu{1000^\circ C}$ to $\pu{300^\circ C}$ happens.

I have this schematic diagram that describes the following scenarios and identifies the regions and the phases at $40 \%\,\ce{Sn}$ alloy from $\pu{800 °C}$ "$\ce{L -> L}$ and $\ce{γ -> L}$, γ, and $\ce{ε  -> L}$ and ε" as an example but it's confusing to follow. However, it's just an example and it doesn't follow the $\ce{Cu}-\ce{Sn}$ phase diagram anyway.

But does the first one mean $\ce{L -> L +  γ}$?

And L , y are in different phases that manages to fall both at $40 \%\,\ce{Sn}$ alloy from $\pu{800 °C}?

Also am I correct to assume that the final one means $\ce{ε -> L + ε}$?

This is the closest image that I can give based on my assumption:

> #### Development of microstructure in eutectic alloys (II)
>
> At compositions between the room temperature solubility limit and the maximum solid solubility at the eutectic temperature, $\beta$ phase nucleates as the $\alpha$ solid solubility is exceeded upon crossing the solvus line
> [image]
>
> **[MSE 2009: Introduction to Materials Science; Chapter 9: Phase Diagrams; Page 28]**

Here's the [PDF file](https://uh.edu/%7Ehfang2/MECE3345/Lectures/Chapter9.pdf) for more information.

"$\ce{L -> L}$ and $\ce{γ -> L}$, γ, and $\ce{ε  -> L}$ and ε" is a schematic diagram for the slow cooling which means it is an equilibrium cooling Like this image given below:

> #### Equilibrium Cooling in a $\ce{Cu-Ni}$ Binary System
>
> Phase Diagram: $\ce{Cu-Ni}$ System.
> System is:
> --binary: *i.e* 2 components: $\ce{Cu}$ and $\ce{Ni}$.
> --isomorphous: i.e., complete solubility of one component in another; a phase field extends from $0$ to $100\,\mathrm{wt}\%$
> Consider $C_o = 35\,\mathrm{wt\%}$ $\ce{Ni}$
>
> [image]

Another one is:

> #### Ex: Cooling of $\ce{Cu-Ni}$ Alloy
>
> Phase diagram: $\ce{Cu-Ni}$ system
> Consider microstructural changes that accompany the cooling of a $C_o = \pu{35 wt\%}\, \ce{Ni}$ alloy
> [image]

> #### Cored vs Equilibrium Structures
>
> $C_o$ changes as we solidify
>
> [image]

These images are from this [PPT file](http://www.engr.mun.ca/%7Easharan/courses/5911_LECTURES/ch09.ppt).

Comment: No. The arrows (you could label each of them with a temperature) have the highest priority, over commas and "and", which are equivalent. Homework: go down starting from 40%/800°C and describe what will happen. (Below 415°C, a further phase appears, btw.) Remember: the unlabeled areas are forbidden, you cannot cross them.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the 40 at% (Sn) composition at 800 °C: it's a liquid.

When you cool it down at around 650 °C you enter a two-phase field: the solid gamma forms (Cu-enriched) and the liquid enriches in Sn. As you further cool down the gamma phase will continue to form, but with progressively higher content of Sn

You cool down at 640 °C and you enter a new different two-phase field: the liquid partially reacts with the gamma phase forming the solid epsilon phase. If you further cool down, the ε phase will continue to form from the liquid, but its composition will progressively enrich in Cu.

Just below 415 °C you enter into another two-phase field: the liquid will solidify into ε and η phase.

That's what occurs by cooling down to 300 °C, but if you further would cool down below 189 °C you will enter another two-phase field; in this case the ε and η' phases will form.

The amounts of the different phases at the different $T$ are obtained by applying the lever rule.

Take care, I described what happened from the thermodynamic point of view (that is what is represented in a phase diagram); the kinetics can remarkably change the things.